# Link in three tables in php redbeans

Tags: mysql, redbean

I have three tables

```
USER
  user_id,name

EVENT
  event_id, name,desc

PARTICIPATION
  id, type
  1    yes
  2    no 
  3    maybe
```

I want to handle relationship among these in table `user_event_participation`

```
id , user_id,event_id,participation_id
1     1        1         3
```

How can I do in redbeans

Comment: can anybody suggest me anything ?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that i don't get the problem fully.
But the way it seems to me is linking.

http://www.redbeanphp.com/link_beans

If you want full example please ask. ( I'm sorry, but I simply don't have much time right now)